# Accessing a property from its attribute

Tags: c#, generics, attributes

Is it possible to access the type of a property from an attribute that has been implemented on to that property?

```
public class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string GetPropertyName()
    {
        // return ??
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    [FooAttribute]
    public int Baz { get; set; }
}
```

I would like GetPropertyName() to return "Baz".

Comment: You can't (Unless you loop through all the types and its properties)

Comment: Didn't think so. Thanks.

Comment: Goodluck. You'll understand my comment later sometime.

Comment: What do you mean "later sometime"?

Comment: You said *Didn't think so*, by that you mean my comment is wrong. Isn't it? I mean you'll eventually realize it is not possible without looping through all the types in the assembly and looping through its properties.(which may take sometime for you to realize it).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I think what *Didn't think so* means is *I didn't think it was possible and your comment helped me understand it really isn't possible*

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Oops, may be.. If that's the case my apologizes to OP.

Comment: Is there a way to mark this as answered?

Comment: @Beakie Not unless Sriram posts it as an actual answer.

Comment: I'll do that in a moment.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sriram Sakthivel is correct that this is not possible but if you are using .net 4.5 you can create a workaround using the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` to pass the caller into the constructor of your attribute, store it and then return it from your `GetPropertyName` method:

```
public class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public FooAttribute([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public string GetPropertyName()
    {
        return PropertyName;   
    }
}
```

This will pass the caller (the property) to the constructor of your attribute.

More details on the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` are available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is not possible. Because Attributes and properties doesn't have "One to One" relationship. You can apply `FooAttribute` to any number of Properties, In such case which property you need to return from `GetPropertyName` method?

As I said in comments you can loop through all the types and its properties to see which are all the properties have `FooAttribute` but obviously that's not what you want.